# ROS navigation real-world implementation?

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering if there are any real-world systems using the ROS navigation package? I'm talking about commercially applied robots. Does anyone have any info of ROS navigation implementations in general as well?

For example: There is a bridge inspection robot and a couple of agricultural robots I know of but they are startups and not completely commercialized AFAIK.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186771/ros-navigation-real-world-implementation-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-07-16**:
So you're looking for active commercial applications that use the ROS navigation stack/metapackage? There are quite a few packages in it. Are you interested in the use of any of them?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-16**:
It seems like a lot of good code structured into a nice integrative format. So I was wondering if anyone was configuring the whole structure for their robots and making it into an actual product. Even examples of implementation of individual packages will be nice.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-16**:
Or is it at this point more of a research and University focused effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/RobotsUsingNavStack

At the very least, Clearpath's robots fit your description.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-16**:
That's true. But then again Clearpath as well is effectively a prototyping platform used by many Universities and research organisations. Have their robots been used in say agriculture or manufacturing or defense or whatever w/ ROS navigation?